# (Javascript + HTML) How to get my select statment answer into my drawing canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am trying to get my code to display to the user their input from the select statement back at them through the canvas drawing. I am not sure how to do this an would appreciate any help. Here is my code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting Card Generator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function draw() {
            var c = document.getElementById("card");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            ctx.strokeRect(125, 25, 960, 540);
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.font = "22px Arial";
            ctx.fillText("Greeting Card", 135, 55);
            document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #div1{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid red;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #div2{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid orange;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Greeting Card Generator</div>
    <div id="div2">
        What Kind of Greeting Would You Like?<select name="greet" id="greet">
            <option value="-1" selected>-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Birthday</option>
            <option value="2">Graduation</option>
            <option value="3">Engagement</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="make card" id="draw" onclick="draw();">  
    </div>    
    <canvas id="card" width="1400" height="900"></canvas>
</body>
```

updated code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Greeting Card Generator</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function draw() {
            var c = document.getElementById("card");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            ctx.strokeRect(125, 25, 960, 540);
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.font = "22px Arial";

            ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("greet").options[document.getElementById("‌​greet").selectedIndex].text, 135, 55);
            document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        #div1{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 24px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid red;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        #div2{
            background-color: cyan;
            font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 25px solid orange;
            padding: 25px;
            width: 50%;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }



    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">Greeting Card Generator</div>
    <div id="div2">
        What Kind of Greeting Would You Like?<select name="greet" id="greet">
            <option value="-1" selected>-Select-</option>
            <option value="1">Birthday</option>
            <option value="2">Graduation</option>
            <option value="3">Engagement</option>
        </select> 
        <br>
        What is the name of the recipient<input type="text" id="name" name="name"/>
        <br>
        What background colour would you like on the card?
        <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgRed" value="red" checked/>Red 
        <input type="radio" name="background" id="bgBlue" value="blue" />Blue 
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="make card" id="draw" onclick="draw();">  
    </div>    
    <canvas id="card" width="1400" height="900"></canvas>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you just stuck with how to get the selected text out of the dropdown and then perhaps use it in place of/in addition to `"Greeting Card"`? Is the rest of your drawing code doing what you expect?

Comment: I have the same feeling as @jamesthorpe. In that case just use `ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("greet").options[document.getElementById("greet").selectedIndex].text, 135, 55)` or better break it up by using a variable or two

Comment: Thank you for responding. Yes I want it to replace "Greeting Card" I was just using it as a placeholder for the time being. The line of code you gave me didn't have the desired outcome im afraid. I'm kind of new at javascript

Comment: @Orphan_Crippler The code you've shown doesn't pop out obvious errors to my eye, but are you aware of how to use the browser's debugger to insert breakpoints? This will let you look at the current values of all variables and would likely help you find the issue. On all browsers it should be F12 to open. It could also be easier to debug if you assign the "greet" element to a local var, like you're doing with "var ctx", before making use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have just made click event work. Remove `onClick event` from your `Button`.

```
var bt = document.querySelector("#draw");
function draw() {
            var c = document.getElementById("card");
            var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
            ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.lineWidth = 10;
            ctx.strokeRect(125, 25, 960, 540);
            ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
            ctx.font = "22px Arial";
            ctx.fillText(document.getElementById("greet").options[document.getElementById("greet").selectedIndex].text, 135, 55);

          document.getElementById("div1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("div2").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
 bt.addEventListener("click",draw);
```